# Pyspark 'from_json', data frame return null for the all json values

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have below logs which contains text and json string

```
2020-09-24T08:03:01.633Z 11.21.23.1 {"EventTime":"2020-09-24 13:33:01","Hostname":"abc-cde.india.local","Keywords":-1234}
```

created DF for the above logs as seen below

```
| Date     |Source IP  | Event Type
|2020-09-24|11.21.23.1 | {"EventTime":"202|
```

crated schema for converting json string to another data frame

```
json_schema = StructType([
        StructField("EventTime", StringType()),
        StructField("Hostname", StringType()),
        StructField("Keywords", IntegerType())
    ])

json_converted_df= df.select(F.from_json(F.col('Event Type'), json_schema).alias("data")).select("data.*").show()
```

but the Data Frame rerun null for all new json schema

```
+---------+--------+--------
|EventTime|Hostname|Keywords|
+---------+--------+--------
|     null|    null|null    |
+---------+--------+--------
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine with me ...

```py
# Preparation of test dataset

a = [
    (
        "2020-09-24T08:03:01.633Z",
        "11.21.23.1",
        '{"EventTime":"2020-09-24 13:33:01","Hostname":"abc-cde.india.local","Keywords":-1234}',
    ),
]

b = ["Date", "Source IP", "Event Type"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(a, b)

df.show()
#+--------------------+----------+--------------------+
#|                Date| Source IP|          Event Type|
#+--------------------+----------+--------------------+
#|2020-09-24T08:03:...|11.21.23.1|{"EventTime":"202...|
#+--------------------+----------+--------------------+

df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
# |-- Source IP: string (nullable = true)
# |-- Event Type: string (nullable = true)
```

```py
# Your code executed
from pyspark.sql.types import *

json_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("EventTime", StringType()),
        StructField("Hostname", StringType()),
        StructField("Keywords", IntegerType()),
    ]
)

json_converted_df = df.select(
    F.from_json(F.col("Event Type"), json_schema).alias("data")
).select("data.*")

json_converted_df.show()
#+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
#|          EventTime|           Hostname|Keywords|
#+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
#|2020-09-24 13:33:01|abc-cde.india.local|   -1234|
#+-------------------+-------------------+--------+

json_converted_df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- EventTime: string (nullable = true)
# |-- Hostname: string (nullable = true)
# |-- Keywords: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: @Adhi What was the issue ? because, apparently, there was no issue at all.

Comment: Hi @Steven, i am not sure what went wrong ... by the way, can you tell me please..what usually cause for returning null value while transforming json string to another DF?

Comment: @Adhi Wrong type in `json_schema`. If you replace `Hostname` type with `IntegerType`, you'll end up with all `NULL`.